# MultiAutoCompleteTextView with transparent list

Tags: android

I'm using [TokenAutoComplete](https://github.com/splitwise/TokenAutoComplete).

The problem, is that the popup with the auto complete items has no style.

[image: a busy cat]

Any ideias why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter for suggestions, you should override the getView and related methods to provide your own layout for the suggestion list items.